# Dynamic SQL Not Converting VARCHAR To INT (shouldn't anyway)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm receiving an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'INSERT INTO TableRowCount (IntFieldID, DecimalField) SELECT 'to data type int"

Using the following code:

```
DECLARE @start INT -- @start is an INT
SET @start = 1 -- INT

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO TableRowCount (IntFieldID, DecimalField)
SELECT ' + @start +', COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.somewhere' -- location is irrelevant

EXECUTE(@sql) -- this is where it fails
```

If I remove `IntFieldID` and the `@start`, it will work with an insert (though it defeats the purpose). I've tried including a `SELECT CAST(' + @start + ' AS INT)`, which seems a little redundant since `@start` is an `INT` already (casting an `INT` as an `INT`), but that doesn't work either.  I also tried beginning with an `N'` **DYNAMIC-SQL**, which didn't work, I tried using three `'''` around everything (didnt' work), and in a few places that I read online, responses suggested putting the variable in the string, which generated the error:

> Must declare scalar variable @start

(no surprise, as that didn't sound correct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your `@Start` to a `varchar`.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO TableRowCount (IntFieldID, DecimalField)
SELECT ' + CAST(@start as nvarchar(20)) +', COUNT(*)
FROM ' + @conn
```

SQL Server implicitly converts between datatypes on concatenation or addition based on some fairly complex criteria.  Suffice to say if you try to combine an `int` and a string it will always attempt to convert the string to an `int` unless you tell it otherwise explicitly.

Below is a conversion chart for your reference [from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Works, but the logic of this escapes me.  I have to convert it to a 'NVARCHAR' in order for it to read, even though it should be an 'INT'?  Sorry, just saw the update.

Comment: You are converting it to a string since you are concatenating it into your SQL string to be executed.

Comment: The reason is that you are trying to make it part of a nvarchar variable.  If you concatentate a string to an int, SQl server will alawys try to convert to the int datatype and of course the string data usally can't convert.

Answer (score 5):

A better way than trying to concatenate an integer is to pass it in as a strongly-typed parameter:

```
DECLARE @start INT = 1;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'INSERT ...
  SELECT @start, COUNT(*) FROM ' + @conn;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@start INT', @start;
```

Comment: Only if you care about SQL injection ;)  +1

Comment: @JNK or if you start adding more variables, different data types, etc. String concatenation is ugly.