# Pass input parameter as column name to update a column value in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `insertvalue` with these three parameters:

```
@stdrollno int,
@sem int,
@IsCheck int,
@subjectname varchar(100),
@test varchar(100)
```

I have a table `demo` where there is table named defaulter where there is a column

```
[Microprocessor th] varchar(50)
[Structured and Object Oriented Analysis and Design th] varchar(50)
```

whose value I have to update.

So in my stored procedure `insertvalue`, I wrote this SQL code:

```
if(@sem = 5)
     BEGIN
        BEGIN
            declare @sql3 nvarchar(500);
            set @sql3 = 'update TEdefaulters 
                        set ['+CAST(@test as nvarchar(100))+'] = ['+CAST(@test as nvarchar(100))+']  + '+CAST(@IsCheck as nvarchar(100))+' 
                        where stdrollno = ' +CAST(@stdrollno as nvarchar(100));

            exec sp_executesql @sql3
          END
          BEGIN
             update TEdefaulters
             set total_theory = total_theory + CONVERT(INT, @ischeck)
             where stdrollno = @stdrollno
          END
          BEGIN
             update TEdefaulters
             set total_attendance = total_attendance + CONVERT(INT, @ischeck)
             where stdrollno = @stdrollno
          END
          BEGIN
                 update TEdefaulters
                 set theory_percentage = (cast((Select total_theory from TEdefaulters where stdrollno=@stdrollno ) as float) / (cast((Select total_theory from TEdefaulters where stdname='total' ) as float))) * 100
                 where stdrollno=@stdrollno
          END
           BEGIN
               update TEdefaulters
              set attendance_percentage = (cast((Select total_attendance from TEdefaulters where stdrollno=@stdrollno ) as float)  /(cast((Select total_attendance from TEdefaulters where stdname='total' )as float))) * 100
              where stdrollno=@stdrollno
          END
      END
```

but it is not working, it causes an error 
The values which work is :

```
exec inserttheoryattendance 5 , 5 , 1 , 'Microprocessor', 'Microprocessor th'
```

the value which does not work is

```
exec inserttheoryattendance 5 , 5 , 1 , 'Structured and Object Oriented Analysis and Design', 'Structured and Object Oriented Analysis and Design th'
```

> Cannot convert nvarchar to int

Comment: Why are you declaring @sql as an int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL Not Converting VARCHAR To INT (shouldn't anyway)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684701/dynamic-sql-not-converting-varchar-to-int-shouldnt-anyway)

Comment: tried that logic, it is not working the conversion does not work

Comment: the error it gives @TabAlleman  " Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' update TEdefaulters 
               set [Microprocessor th] =  [Microprocessor th]  + 0 
       where stdrollno = ' to data type int."

Comment: The fix to your issue is the same as the fix in the duplicate question.   In other words, all non-string datatypes need to be cast as strings when building your dynamic sql statement.   Casting the strings as integers is the OPPOSITE of what you need to do.

Comment: but why it is giving error ??? i casted it as varchar but it still gives always the same error.

Comment: it gives new error : Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Microprocessor th'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'Microprocessor th'.  @TabAlleman

Comment: no i cannot find it all single quotes are correct @TabAlleman

Comment: the entire stored procedure goes to red color

Comment: @tab alleman could i use double quotation??

Comment: @TabAlleman still it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> declare @sql nvarchar(50);

50 characters is too short for your SQL String.   Try changing it to `nvarchar(500)`

Comment: yes, i did that earlier and it worked before. but some for some strings it is working and for some not, especially for bigger one. the data is updated but then it throws an error : String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.. this happens after data is updated in table

Comment: So how do i correct it? Because it works for some data and some not

Comment: how can the data be wrong? some data is getting inserted properly, for some data gets inserted and then throws out an error

Comment: yes i checked for it and i made the column varchar(max) and have the stored procedure at nvarchar(4000). still throws an error. data gets inserted first and then throws the error. error does not happen first

Comment: Can you post a script that completely reproduces the problem?   Otherwise I can't help; because there is no way to see what is the problem in your data.

Comment: sorry i missed it here while typing, but while passing i pass it properly

Comment: Add the rest of your stored procedure definition to your question, including the parameter assignments.

Comment: it is a very big stored procedure , it just repeats the same statements but with different sem, and value goes in different table

Comment: Well, make the `@Test` parameter and the `@SubjectName` parameter bigger, and everywhere that they are inserted into a table, make that column bigger too.

Comment: I made them varchar(500) still did not work. Column varchar(max)